# Sort a list in all possible ways in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Let's suppose we make this list

```
a=[1,2,3]
```

a can be sorted in 6 possible ways

```
a=[1,2,3]
a=[1,3,2]
a=[2,1,3]
a=[2,3,1]
a=[3,1,2]
a=[3,2,1]
```

How do I make a function that automatically does that but with bigger lists?

Answer (score 2):

The thing is called permutations and you can use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) lib.

Here is the example:

```
from itertools import permutations

print list(permutations([1, 2, 3]))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```